# getting the url of the current open tab of opera, firefox and Brave browser using pywinauto

Tags: python, firefox, opera, pywinauto, brave

I am working on a project that requires the URL of a tab open in a browser window. Till now I have done the code for Chrome and Edge but am unable for Opera, Firefox, and Brave browser. Any amount of help would be appreciated.
This is my progress till far.

```py
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

time.sleep(3)
window = GetForegroundWindow()
tid, pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)

# chrome

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=pid, time_out=10)
dlg = app.top_window()
url = dlg.child_window(title="Address and search bar", control_type="Edit").get_value()
print(url)

# edge 

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(process=pid, found_index=0)
dlg = app.top_window()
wrapper = dlg.child_window(title="App bar", control_type="ToolBar")
url = wrapper.descendants(control_type='Edit')[0].get_value()
print(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application
browser_title = "Opera"  # Change this to "Firefox" or "Brave" depending on the browser
def get_browser_url(browser_title):
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title=browser_title)
    window = app.top_window()
    address_bar = window.child_window(title="Address and search bar", control_type="Edit")
    url = address_bar.get_value()
    return url

current_url = get_browser_url(browser_title)
print(current_url)
```

Comment: Not working sir giving me this error   
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Opera', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}

Comment: Try `connect(title_re=browser_title)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code for Chrome is not necessarily exclusive to Chrome; it works for Brave as well. Below is your code, practically unchanged, showing the URL of the active tab in a Brave window (i.e. "brave.com"). The results are shown in the terminal at the bottom of the Visual Studio Code window. Python 3.8.10 (64-bit) was used.

[image]

Opera will require a different [control identifier](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=control_identifiers#pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.print_control_identifiers).

Side note, if you're curious which identifiers are available, you can call `print_control_identifiers()` to get a detailed breakdown. Here is a portion of the results for an Opera instance:

```
Control Identifiers:

Pane - 'Secure, Fast...'    (L123, T229, R868, B663)
['Secure, Fast...', 'Pane', 'Secure, Fast...', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
child_window(title="Secure, Fast...", control_type="Pane")
   | 
   | Document - 'Browser DOWNLOADS'    (L171, T310, R860, B655)
   | ['Browser DOWNLOADS', 'Document', 'Document0', 'Document1']
   | child_window(title="Browser DOWNLOADS", auto_id="21440384", control_type="Document")
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L131, T229, R860, B655)
   | ['Pane3', 'Browse privately.', 'Browse privately.Pane0', 'Browse privately.Pane1']
   | 
   | TitleBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   | ['TitleBar']
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L131, T229, R860, B655)
   | ['Pane4', 'Browse privately. Search privately. And ditch Big Tech.Pane2']
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - 'Browser non-client'    (L131, T229, R860, B655)
   |    | ['Browser non-clientPane', 'Pane5', 'Browser non-client']
   |    | child_window(title="Browser non-client", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Pane - ''    (L131, T230, R860, B655)
   |    |    | ['Pane8', 'Browse privately. Search privately. And ditch Big Tech.Pane3']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L171, T230, R860, B655)
   |    |    |    | ['Pane9', 'Browse privately. Search privately. And ditch Big Tech.Pane4']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Toolbar - 'Navigation'    (L171, T271, R860, B310)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Navigation', 'Toolbar', 'NavigationToolbar']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Navigation", control_type="ToolBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L173, T276, R858, B305)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane10']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - 'Address bar'    (L310, T276, R787, B305)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit', 'Edit0', 'Edit1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Address bar", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - 'Address field'    (L395, T276, R546, B305)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Address field", control_type="Edit")
```

Note at the bottom of the (truncated) output we find the following:

```
child_window(title="Address field", control_type="Edit")
```

Using this title, instead of "Address and search bar" for Chrome/Brave, will successfully return the expected data (note that the protocol is also returned with the address in Opera, whereas it is excluded in Brave/Chrome):

[image]

I hope this is helpful!